# Sent email from C# using outlook gets stored in outbox instead

Tags: c#, email, outlook-2010

I have a `C#` application which uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` to send email. Everything works fine and I have attached parts of my code below:

```
// Create the Outlook application.
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
// Create a new mail item.
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

// Add email info text.
oMsg.HTMLBody = m_eMailBody;
oMsg.Subject = m_mailSubject;

// Add a recipient.
Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(hostEmail);
oRecip.Resolve();
// Send E-Mail via Outlook.
try
{
    ((Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Send();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
...
```

Once `Send()` is called two things may happen:

- **If Internet connection is available**, the mail will actually be **sent**.
- **If No Internet connection**, the mail will be **stored** in outlooks outbox. I would like to know this so I can inform user, what should I do?

I tried using `(Outlook._MailItem)oMsg).Sent` but it just throws exceptions.
Is there any way to really finding out if emails were really sent or not, Any ideas?

Comment: I would try to find out whether there are any items in the Outbox. If they stay there for more than a few minutes, something is probably wrong (might be the network connection or the server or something).